# How to run an external command, showing its progress without locking Blender? (Escape to cancel for eg)

Tags: python, external-applications

Currently if you run an external process from Python the command and locks  Blender until it finishes, eg:
`subprocess.check_output(["sleep", "2"])`.

Whats the best way to wrap an external call in way that the user can see whats happening, and can escape from if its taking too long?

Comment: Note, am investigating a good way to do this, asking Q since this seems generally useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

External processes can be run while collecting their output using [non-blocking file reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python).

This example uses a mix-in class *(works the same way as Import/ExportHelper)* which you can subclass to create your own operator that runs a command.

Each line printed by the external application shows in the header,
and pressing escape kills the process.

---

Notes:

- For reliable updates, the process your calling may need to explicitly flush the standard output (`sys.stdout.flush()` in Python).
- This only works with a recent build & upcoming 2.77 (a minor change was needed [commit](http://developer.blender.org/rBf6ff8f27e35d7b9596bbb2c55c3cf464f6e6ffc0)).
- Unfortunately, non-blocking reading from a processes requires some black magic with `ctypes`.
  Though it [may be supported in Python3.6](http://bugs.python.org/issue12939)).
- In practice you may want to have a cleanup operation when canceling. (if the process works on temp files for example).

Example script:

```
"""
To test this operator, run the script, then open operator search (space-bar)
to execute: External Command Example
"""

import subprocess
import os

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Portable non-blocking pipe.
#
# This is really black magic on ms-windows!


if os.name == "nt":
    def pipe_non_blocking_set(fd):
        # Constant could define globally but avoid polluting the name-space
        # see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35052424/432509
        import msvcrt

        from ctypes import windll, byref, wintypes, WinError, POINTER
        from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE, DWORD, BOOL

        LPDWORD = POINTER(DWORD)

        PIPE_NOWAIT = wintypes.DWORD(0x00000001)

        def pipe_no_wait(pipefd):
            SetNamedPipeHandleState = windll.kernel32.SetNamedPipeHandleState
            SetNamedPipeHandleState.argtypes = [HANDLE, LPDWORD, LPDWORD, LPDWORD]
            SetNamedPipeHandleState.restype = BOOL

            h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(pipefd)

            res = windll.kernel32.SetNamedPipeHandleState(h, byref(PIPE_NOWAIT), None, None)
            if res == 0:
                print(WinError())
                return False
            return True

        return pipe_no_wait(fd)


    def pipe_non_blocking_is_error_blocking(ex):
        if not isinstance(ex, PortableBlockingIOError):
            return False
        from ctypes import GetLastError
        ERROR_NO_DATA = 232

        return (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_DATA)

    PortableBlockingIOError = OSError
else:
    def pipe_non_blocking_set(fd):
        import fcntl
        fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        return True

    # only to keep compatibility with nt version
    def pipe_non_blocking_is_error_blocking(ex):
        if not isinstance(ex, PortableBlockingIOError):
            return False
        return True

    PortableBlockingIOError = BlockingIOError



# end magic!
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


class SubprocessHelper:
    """
    Mix-in class for operators to run commands in a non-blocking way.

    This uses a modal operator to manage an external process.

    This class defines:

        process: The running process object.

    Subclass must define:

        command: Sequence of arguments to pass to subprocess.Popen
    """

    @staticmethod
    def _non_blocking_readlines(f, chunk=64):
        """
        Iterate over lines, yielding b'' when nothings left
        or when new data is not yet available.
        """

        fd = f.fileno()
        pipe_non_blocking_set(fd)

        blocks = []

        while True:
            try:
                data = os.read(fd, chunk)
                if not data:
                    # case were reading finishes with no trailing newline
                    yield b''.join(blocks)
                    blocks.clear()
            except PortableBlockingIOError as ex:
                if not pipe_non_blocking_is_error_blocking(ex):
                    raise ex

                yield b''
                continue

            while True:
                n = data.find(b'\n')
                if n == -1:
                    break

                yield b''.join(blocks) + data[:n + 1]
                data = data[n + 1:]
                blocks.clear()
            blocks.append(data)

    def _report_output(self):
        stdout_line_iter, stderr_line_iter = self._buffer_iter
        for line_iter, report_type in (
                (stdout_line_iter, {'INFO'}),
                (stderr_line_iter, {'WARNING'})
                ):
            while True:
                line = next(line_iter).rstrip()  # rstrip all, to include \r on windows
                if not line:
                    break
                self.report(report_type, line.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogateescape'))

    def _wm_enter(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        window = context.window

        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        context.window.cursor_set('WAIT')

    def _wm_exit(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        window = context.window

        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        window.cursor_set('DEFAULT')


    def modal(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        p = self._process

        if event.type == 'ESC':
            self.cancel(context)
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Operation aborted by user.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        elif event.type == 'TIMER':
            if p.poll() is not None:
                self._report_output()
                self._wm_exit(context)
                return {'FINISHED'}

            self._report_output()

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        import subprocess
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(
                    self.command,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    )
        except FileNotFoundError as ex:
            # Command not found
            self.report({'ERROR'}, str(ex))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        self._process = p
        self._buffer_iter = (
                iter(self._non_blocking_readlines(p.stdout)),
                iter(self._non_blocking_readlines(p.stderr)),
                )

        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)

        self._wm_enter(context)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        self._wm_exit(context)
        self._process.kill()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# End generic code, now to show an example operator using SubprocessHelper

import bpy
from bpy.types import (
        Operator,
        )


class MyCommandOperator(Operator, SubprocessHelper):
    bl_idname = "wm.my_command"
    bl_label = "External Command Example"

    command = (
        # Run Blender's Python, but could be any other command.
        bpy.app.binary_path_python,
        # pass in a script to execute
        "-c", """
import sys
import time

# Some dummy status reports
status_report = ('Hello World', 'Blender is working!', '... almost done', 'Task Complete!')

for word in status_report:
    # Will show in the info area.
    print(word)
    # flush to ensure we get the output immediately.
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # wait a second.
    time.sleep(1.0)
"""
        )


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyCommandOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyCommandOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # bpy.ops.wm.my_command('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Update, this now works on windows.