# How to access the bundled Python executable for subprocess in Blender scripts?

Tags: python

There is now a python executable in the blender install folder, It's clearly said that it was included for subprocesses purposes (here : https://developer.blender.org/T43486)

But how can we access it through scripts ?

Answer (score 3):

The path to access this is [`bpy.app.binary_path_python`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.html#bpy.app.binary_path_python)

The exact details on how you should run the process are up to you, and not Blender spesific.

Best try the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, but `os.system` will work too.

Heres a very simple example calling a Python sub-process.

```
import bpy
import subprocess
import time

command = (
    bpy.app.binary_path_python,
    "-c", "import time; time.sleep(2)",
    )
proc = subprocess.Popen(command)

while proc.poll() is None:
    print("Waiting...")
    time.sleep(0.1)

print("Finished with exit code %d" % proc.returncode)
```

For an example of how to run Python as a subprocess without locking up Blender, see [this Q & A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45731).