# Can I use code in Cycles Mode that will run my human baby AI?

Tags: python

I'm creating a real learning human baby in Blender Cycles. To create the "brain" or "AI" I must of course use code. But, can I run code in Cycles mode? I don't want to be in BGE mode. P.S. I don't need interactivity.

For example I'll need the code to move armatures, get numbers from a accelo-meter in the baby and use the numbers in the code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using python you can create an animation that can be played back and rendered using any render engine at a later time.

```
bone.rotation_euler.x = 15.0
bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=10)
```

As you want to read external data while creating your animation you might want to look at [using the subprocess module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45731/935) to keep blender responsive.

Without wanting interactivity you could capture your data to a text file and have your script read it in to create the animation.

```
with open('mydata.csv') as csvfile:
    inFile = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in inFile:
        bone.rotation_euler.x = row[1]
        bone.rotation_euler.y = row[2]
        bone.rotation_euler.z = row[3]
        bone.keyframe_insert('rotation_euler', frame=row[0])
```

Comment: Are you suggesting for me to use BGE and then render in ex. Cycles? I don't want to use BGE, it has worse Physics than Cycles does and doesn't allow Constraints.

Comment: No, nothing there refers to the game engine. You can use python to keyframe an animation the same as you can do by hand.

Comment: "python to keyframe an animation the same as you can do by hand" But can the code change, grab numbers from sensors, use those, update etc as I originally asked in my question?

Comment: The second example reads data from a file, you can change that to accepting data from a [network connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) or from a [serial port](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial/3.3).... whatever python is capable of using to get data.